# How to retrieve a view's background color and compare it to a color resource

Tags: android

I'm trying to compare whether the background color of one of my views is equal to a color resource I created and haven't found anything that works.

I'm willing to use any method, whether converting to HEX or String or Int, as long as it works. Here's an example of my current method.

I set the background color of a view with:

```
chosenColor.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tag_pink));
```

When I retrieve it using this method:

```
ColorDrawable chosenColorBox = (ColorDrawable) chosenColor.getBackground();  
int colorId =  chosenColorBox.getColor();

colorId == `-611329`
```

Using `Integer.toString` on `R.color.tag_pink` shows the value as `2130968581` which obviously can't be compared in an `if` statement" with the retrieved value.

What's the best way to do this so I don't have to resort to hard-coding the individual values, which prevents me from adjusting the color resources?

Comment: SOLUTION: colorId != getResources().getColor(R.color.tag_no_tag_chosen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to compare the color to `Context.getResources().getColor(R.color.tag_pink)` instead of the resource's ID (which is not the color!). The returned value represents the color in the form of `0xAARRGGBB`.

Comment: Thanks so much, Raz. It worked. I should have realized that I was referencing the ID instead of the color. Answer accepted and final solution is as follows. (colorId != getResources().getColor(R.color.tag_no_tag_chosen))

Answer (score 1):

Just simple Answer:

```
int viewColor=((ColorDrawable) YOUR_VIEW.getBackground()).getColor();

if(viewColor==Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"){
  //Color matched
}
```